# pass javascript filename in a string?

Tags: javascript

I have many JS object literal files in my code. In a JS function

```
data=data9.webb9[i];
```

I am accesing it in this way 
with help of

script type="text/javascript" src="webdata"> script

in head tag

How could I

do something like this:

```
data=file[i];
```

where file=data9.web9 or data10.web10 and so on... according to function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`switch( SomeFunction() )
{
case 1:
    file = data9.web9;
    break;
case 2:
    file = data10web10;
    break;
default:
    file = data.web;
}`

data = file[i]; //file=data9.web9 or data10.web10 and so on... according to function call.